# Do React Native images impact on the bundle loading time?

Tags: react-native

I have a dictionary within an `assets/img/index.js` folder where I export the references to all the images in the code.

Later on, I do `import * as allImages from 'assets/img'`. Images later are iterated or cherry picked, depending on the view.

My bundle load time, sometimes, takes a lot. At worst 4s in some apps. Should I stop using this pattern?